# Android catching Exceptions

Tags: android

I have an exception that I'd like to handle, but I cannot tell its origin based on the stack trace (`NsdManager.java:338` isn't mine and that files only has 58 lines). None of the files it references are mine.

Is there a way to handle any exception that comes up from the Handler?

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: NsdManager
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.net.nsd.NsdManager$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(NsdManager.java:338)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I am using a handler to help discover/rediscover a network based service when WiFi switches on and off.

**Edit: Pastie of code**

- [Full Stack Trace](http://pastie.org/8700725)
- [MainActivity](http://pastie.org/8700708)
- [NsdHelper](http://pastie.org/8700715)
- [WifiBroadcastReceiver](http://pastie.org/8700712)
- [WsHelper](http://pastie.org/8700717)
- [NsdManager](http://pastie.org/8700731) - Line 338 doesn't exist here, so I don't know what code to wrap in a Try/Catch.

Thanks

Comment: Post full stacktrace. And codes.

Comment: this looks like something that happened under the hood for you unless `MsdManager` was written by you, in that case, wrap the area of line 338 there in a try catch

Comment: Added pasties to full code that i've written/edited.

Comment: By looking at the package name (`android.net.nsd`), I don't think he has control over the class. On the other hand, it is possible to download and see the original Android source code from SDK manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the NSD Manager has some long standing problems

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35585

[jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) works much better.